# Problem exporting Pandas DataFrame with object containing documents as bytes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I am trying to export a DataFrame that contains documents as byte objects, however, I can not find a suitable file format that does not involve the relatively small (*memory usage: 254.3+ KB*) DataFrame expanding into something in the range of 100's of MB - even 1GB+.

So far I have tried to export the DataFrame as CSV and HDF5.

The column causing this huge expansion contains either .pdf, .doc, .txt or .msg  files in byteformat:
`b'%PDF-1.7\r%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\r\n256...`
which was initially stored on a SQL-server as `varbinary(max)` and loaded by pandas default settings.

I have simply tried using pandas to export the DataFrame using:
`df.to_csv('.csv')` and

```
data_stored = pd.HDFStore('documents.h5')
data_stored['document'] = df
```

I wanted to keep the output data compact, as I would simply like to be able to load the data again at another time. The problem, however, is that the exports result in either a huge CSV or .h5 file. I guess there is some file-format that keeps the format and size of a pd.DataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exporting using `df.to_pickle`. Also I discovered that the size of the dataframe was indeed much larger than I initially thought, since the `pandas` method `.info` did not include the enormous amount of overhead memory. Instead, to view the entire memory, I used `df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()` and indeed the dataframe took up around `1.1 GB`.